# Splitting ID of element to return only the number

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have this line of code:

```
<a href="#" id="inv_1" class="load_invoice">
```

I am trying to use Javascript to spit back only the integer to be used for the rest of my control. What is the best method to do so?

Would .split be used or a simple regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use 'replace' for such things:

```
var myvar = 'inv_1';
myvar = myvar.replace('inv_','');
// myvar is now 1
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

You can also use 'split':

```
var myvar = 'inv_1';
myvar = myvar.split('_');
// myvar[1] is now 1
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Ah! Thanks Ray. Will keep that handy. Appreciate it.